# How to use pagination on dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

How can you make a paginated request (limit, offset, and sort_by) using dynamoDB?
On mysql you can:

> SELECT... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1 order by created_date ASC

I'm trying this using nodejs, and in this case `created_date` isn't the primary key, can I query using sort key `created_date`?

This is my `users` table

```
{
    "user_id": "asa2311",
    "created_date": "2019/01/18 15:05:59",
    "status": "A",
    "rab_item_id": "0",
    "order_id": "1241241",
    "description": "testajabroo",
    "id": "e3f46600-1af7-11e9-ac22-8d3a3e79a693",
    "title": "test"
},
{
    "user_id": "asa2311",
    "status_id": "D",
    "created_date": "2019/01/18 14:17:46",
    "order_id": "1241241",
    "rab_item_id": "0",
    "description": "testajabroo",
    "id": "27b5b0d0-1af1-11e9-b843-77bf0166a09f",
    "title": "test"
},
{
    "user_id": "asa2311",
    "created_date": "2019/01/18 15:05:35",
    "status": "A",
    "rab_item_id": "0",
    "order_id": "1241241",
    "description": "testajabroo",
    "id": "d5879e70-1af7-11e9-8abb-0fa165e7ac53",
    "title": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination in DynamoDB is handled by setting the `ExclusiveStartKey` parameter to the `LastEvaluatedKey` returned from the previous result. There is no way to start after a specific number of items like you can with `OFFSET` in MySQL.

Comment: There is also a limit property on the query you can have to set. Otherwise it will return entire data set even if you have set ExclusiveStartKey.

Comment: You are limited to 1 mb of data per page IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that.